# Prevent double-frame with mdframed/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I want to create a digression using mdframed. I want it to have rounded corners, so I load it with option [framemethod=tikz]. Because of this, the problem arises that the standard framebox I use for my tikzpictures is also put around the mdframed-box, resulting in a really ugly double-frame. I tried the advice I got in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173837/how-to-prevent-frames-on-each-groupplot-in-tikz-pgfplots) question, but I couldn´t pass the TikZ-key to mdframed.

[image: MWE-pic]

What I ultimately want to achieve is a frame with rounded corners and grey background. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={framed,background rectangle/.style={draw=black!80,rounded corners=.5ex}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black!10!white]
Plain text.
Or something else.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent the outer frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to disable the `every picture` style for `mdframe`, you can use:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{mdframed}{%
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={}}%
}
```

and then use `\mdfsetup{}` to apply the `roundcorner` to the mdframe:

```
\mdfsetup{roundcorner=.5ex}
```

This way the `tikzpicture` environment still gets the desired frame, and the `mdframe` does not get affected:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={framed,background rectangle/.style={draw=red!80,rounded corners=.5ex, inner sep=0pt}}}%

\AtBeginEnvironment{mdframed}{%
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={}}%
}
\mdfsetup{roundcorner=.5ex}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black!10!white]
Plain text.
Or something else.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. However, this results in the frame being a little to wide... Also, the backgroundcolor only fills to the inner frame.

Comment: @Paul: Please update the question with a MWE the shows the background fill problem. Also, is the purpose of the `tikzset{every picture...} for the `mdframed` or is it also for other pictures as well?

Comment: Updated the question, sorry I didn´t include it in the first place. The purpose of the tikz-frame-option is solely for other pictures, not for the mdframed stuff. It would be okay for me to deactivate it globally for mdframed, but I want to keep it for my other pictures.

Comment: @Paul: Ok, have revised answer.